# How can I convert int to str in this code?

Tags: python, sum, typeerror

```
t = int (input())
for i in range(t): 
    A,B = map(int,input().split())
    print(int('Case #%d:' + (A+B) %t))
```

This code gets number of times(t) the loop is going to repeat,
gets two numbers from the user and prints out the sum of two numbers

however,

I get a type error that says "must be str not int"
how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm not clear what this `print(int('Case #%d:' + (A+B) %t))` is supposed to be doing

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 2):

Your print statement is wrong, use this:

```
t = int (input())
for i in range(t): 
    A,B = map(int,input().split())
    print(f'Case #{i}: {A+B}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make the print statement content into an int, but you can do this instead:

```
t = int(input())


for i in range(t):
    res = input("input string")
    res = res.split()
    print(res)
    A, B = map(int, res)
    print('Case #%d:' %t + str(A+B))
```

Returning for t = 2, and res = 2, 3 and 4, 5:

```
input string2 3
['2', '3']
Case #2:5
input string4 5
['4', '5']
Case #2:9
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
t = int (input())
for i in range(t): 
    A,B = map(int,input().split())
    print('Case #{case}:{sum}'.format(case = i,sum= A+B))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cases = int(input())

for i in range(cases):
    a,b = map(int, input().split())
    ans = a + b
    print("Case #%s: %s"%(i+1, ans ))
```

Thanks for the contribution! so I tried this way and it worked as well!